Do we want posts with <= -8 score to always appear on Meta Arqade's homepage?
Currently, if a Meta post hits -8 score, it is hidden from the home page of Meta Arqade. In my opinion, this can stifle a discussion, as on Meta sites, votes are generally taken to represent either agreement or disagreement of a topic. So, if 8 early users see it and leave a downvote, others that view Meta later might miss it.
Another side effect (although probably a lesser one) is any post with < -8 score can effectively be edited by anyone with over 2,000 reputation without oversight or review, as the editor has enough rep to make immediate edits (i.e. not going through the "suggested edit" review), and the post will not be bumped to the home page. As a demonstration, I edited this post at the same time I posted this question. You will note that (as of writing) it does not appear on the Meta homepage.
What can be done
A change was recently made to allow sites to choose to allow posts at -8 on the Meta homepage. The change is opt-in, so I ask, do we want to opt in?

NB: it'll be ironic if this ends up with -8 votes and falls off the Meta Home page.

Very good observation, and thanks for bringing this up!

[status-review] - with nothing but positive feedback for the last two weeks here, can we get this feature changed please? To be clear: allow posts with <= -8 to appear on Meta). (I'm not sure if the option is worded in the positive i.e. "enable -8 posts" or in the negative i.e. "disable the check that hides -8 posts", if that makes sense).

Yes, we should allow downvoted meta posts to appear on the homepage
Meta posts, even those with negative scores, should remain visible to foster open discussion and ensure new users aren't inadvertently silenced.
Hiding downvoted meta posts effectively stifles discussions. Unlike the main site, votes on meta often represent agreement or disagreement rather than post quality. By allowing negatively scored posts to remain visible, we encourage a more diverse range of opinions and ensure that all voices have a chance to be heard.
This change would be particularly beneficial for new users who may not yet fully understand our site policies or community consensus. If a newcomer makes a suggestion that's initially unpopular, hiding their post from the feed could shut down further discussion prematurely. Instead, keeping these posts visible allows for constructive feedback, helping users understand why their ideas might not have been well-received and potentially leading to more refined proposals in the future.
The nature of meta discussions sometimes involves controversial topics or proposals for change. By maintaining visibility for all posts, regardless of score, we create a more inclusive environment where dissenting opinions can be addressed openly.
This approach aligns with the reasons provided in the Meta Stack Exchange post linked in the original question: Hiding downvoted questions silences important discussions on Meta.
